# What to know when buying a used car from Canada?

Tags: united-states, taxes, canada, car, fees

I'm in the market for a used pickup and I found one with the options I like, but it's in Canada (I'm in the USA). I'm mostly concerned about crossing the border on the way back - it's just a bill of sale and the title ok, and are there any import taxes or fees I should be aware of?

The particular vehicle is a 2015 F-150. I've been told there is no tax because it was made in the USA, is that correct?

Are there any taxes or fees I would need to pay to Canada?

Comment: Are you sure it is legal to register the car in the US? It might not matter where it was made, but what market it was made for.

Comment: Lots and lots of info [here](https://www.cbp.gov/trade/basic-import-export/importing-car). Too much for me to try to put into an answer. Among other things, it says duty is 25%...